# kubernetes mongodb non-root keyfile secret permission denied

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, file-permissions

I followed this [post](http://pauldone.blogspot.com/2017/06/deploying-mongodb-on-kubernetes-gke25.html) to create a mongodb StatefulSet

When I try to run as a non-root User, mongo encounters a permission denied error while trying to read the keyFile (a Secret, PodSpec.volumes[n].secret.defaultMode=256)

How can I run as a non-root User and still have permission to read the file?  It seems like I need to set the Secret/file ownership to the non-root User, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Also, I've been doing some reading on understanding file permissions, but I'm not all that familiar with it

Comment: For anyone interested, I got it working by moving the init script to a ConfigMap.  The init script was originally being loaded in the Docker build.  I moved it to a ConfigMap and referenced in Kubernetes YAML and the permission error didn't occur.  Also, I checked file permissions in both cases (leaving out the key reference) and they were the same: `lrwxrwxrwx`

Comment: I lied.  Still not working

Comment: Realized that's the link and not the file itself... seems the Secret-file has different permissions....?

Comment: this is an old post, but did you get this working? I'm also having this issue and cant find anything useful to help me.

Comment: I am sorry, this isnt old. I thought it was Feb 2015 (lmfao)

Comment: Ended up using X509 cert auth for mongo.  It doesn't throw the "permissions too open" error on the certificate file.  It seems you can't change the owner of a Secret mounted file

Comment: I found out about that too. It seems to be a limitation for now :( sad, I had to create a custom image just to change the ownership of the secret. And feels so dirty.

Answer (score 0):

Hello from the future,

I figured out what is wrong. The post you referenced incorrectly generates the mongodb secret.

I created a fixed implementation that correctly uses mongo secrets with the right permissions and also uses local storage with minikube here:

https://github.com/MichaelScript/kubernetes-mongodb

I found this out by running `kubectl get secrets mongosecret -o yaml` and realizing it had no data...